# Can one entity be persisted to multiple persistence units using OpenJPA?

Tags: java, persistence, openjpa

I'm trying to save an entity to two separate persistence units one after the other. I can successfully save the entity to the first unit, I then detach it from that unit, reset the `@Id` value and persist to the second, but it appears that the object still has an associated id that is possibly not set-able? I think it's called the oid? The error:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal store error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: The instance 
of type "class za.co.core.ejb.entities.Address" with oid "4" no longer 
exists in the data store.  This may mean that you deleted the instance 
in a separate transaction, but this context still has a cached version.
```

I know I can create a brand new object and copy the values I want across, but I want to do this generically without knowing too much about the object itself.

My code looks like this:

```
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "puOpenJPA_MSSQL", 
      type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "puOpenJPA_MSSQLaudit", 
      type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
   private EntityManager auditManager;

   ...

   entityManager.persist(entity);
   entityManager.detach(entity);

   entity.setId(null); //this sets the @id property of the entity to null
   auditManager.persist(entity); //exception thrown
```

And here is the persistence.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"         
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="puOpenJPA_MSSQL" transaction-type="JTA">
           <provider>
              org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
           </provider>
           <jta-data-source>
              java:jboss/datasources/mySqlSandbox
           </jta-data-source>
           <class>
              za.co.core.ejb.entities.AuditableEntity
           </class>
           <class>za.co.core.ejb.entities.Address</class>
           <properties>
               <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
                 value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
               <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" 
                 value="org.apache.openjpa" />
               <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" 
                 value="false"/>
       </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

   <persistence-unit name="puOpenJPA_MSSQLaudit" transaction-type="JTA">
       <provider>
         org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
       </provider>
       <jta-data-source>
          java:jboss/datasources/mySqlSandboxAudit
       </jta-data-source>
       <class>za.co.core.ejb.entities.AuditableEntity</class>
       <class>za.co.core.ejb.entities.Address</class>

       <properties>
           <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
             value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
           <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" 
             value="org.apache.openjpa" />
           <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" 
             value="false" />
       </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Are you sure the entity referred in the exception is the entity you are saving, it could be a related entity referenced from the entity passed to the persist method, in that case you should detach it too or mark the relationship with `CascadeType.MERGE` or `CascadeType.ALL` .

Comment: Good point. I only have one entity, inherited from a mapped super class. No relationships as yet.

Comment: Can you post `persistence.xml`, I'm not even able to declare two persistence units with the same entity classes, I use EclipseLink and I don't know if this is a limitation of it.

Comment: @remigio Added the persistence.xml

Comment: I've tested your code with a single persistence unit (as I was saying before EclipseLink doesn't allow me to define two with the same entities definitions, but I don't think this is relevant to your issue) and it runs smoothly, so I think that could be an OpenJPA bug.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes because entities are "plain old java objects", but in practice to make all that magic work the persistence provider proxies parts of it, like collection members. As soon as you persist it, its not 'your' entity anymore - its part of the provider's bookkeeping.

If you want to persist the same entity multiple times, clone it multiple times and persist each individual copy.

Comment: As soon as an entity is detached it's no more 'part of the provider's bookkeeping', it goes back to its previous POJO status.

Comment: @remigio that's what I thought too, but in practice it's clearly not the case. There are other properties that are inherited that keep information about the persistence context. In my opinion calling `detach(entity)` should clear all that, but it doesn't.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee You're right as soon as the internal properties attached from JPA remain there once the entity is detached, after all it's still an entity and still carries on the internal JPA field members. However from a logical point of view it's no more attached to the persistence context and so can be used as a pojo. I've tested your code with a single persistence unit (as I was saying before EclipseLink doesn't allow me to define two with the same entities definitions, but I don't think this is relevant to your issue) and it runs smoothly, so I think that could be an OpenJPA bug.

Comment: @remigio -- Your first statement is not entirely correct. While a detached Entity isn't actively tracked, OpenJPA will still do some amount of tracking on detached Entities to enable more efficient merging. Your best bet would be clone your Entity instance for each PU you want to persist it in.